# javascript to calculate values in gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview

```
 <asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" CssClass="vutblrow" TabIndex="3" HeaderStyle-CssClass="vutblhdr" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"  Width="25%" PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages"


            AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcreated="Gridview1_RowCreated" Height="16px">
              <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"  Height="25px" BorderStyle="Solid" />
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Serial Number" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Air/Bus/Train Fare">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="txtBoxNormalmedium" ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City To">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="txtBoxNormalmedium" ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City From">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass="txtBoxNormalmedium"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row"
                        onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" CssClass="btnNormalAdd" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click" CssClass="lnkbut">Remove</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:gridview>

 <asp:Label ID="lblgpf14" runat="server" CssClass="lblText " Text="Total Air Fare"></asp:Label>      
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" CssClass="txtBoxNormalmedium" Enabled="False" onkeyup="Calculate();"></asp:TextBox>
```

When user types in the air/bus/train fare the value should be displayed in the textbox "txt" (using the onkeyup in javacript) this textbox is outside the gridview.When the user clicks on Add new row and enters the train fare the total value must be displayed in "txt".I really have no idea on how to write a javascript for this.can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event where user enters value (here at two palces according to your question) say like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="texboxid" onkeyup="showCal(this)" />
```

your js script

```
function showCal(obj){

  var val=document.getElementById(obj.id).value;


      if(val!='' && !isNaN(val) ){
         var prvVal=document.getElementById('txt').value;
         prvVal= (!isNaN(prvVal))?prvVal:0;
        document.getElementById('txt').value = parseInt(prvVal)+parseInt(val);
      }else{
         alert("The value you have entered is either empty or not a number.")
      }
}
```

Comment: will this even get the gridview textbox value?

Comment: i actually didnt understand...i wrote this function and i added the onkeyup in the required textboxes..but it doesnt seem to be working...

Comment: function showCal(obj) {

    var val = document.getElementById(obj.id).value;


      if(val!='' && !isNaN(val) ){
          var prvVal = document.getElementById('txt').value;
         prvVal= (!isNaN(prvVal))?prvVal:0;
         document.getElementById('txt').value = parseInt(prvVal) + val;
      }
}
</script> This keeps on repeating the values in the textbox and when i click on remove it doesnt remove the value from the text box

Comment: what do mean by saying ..."repeating the value" ? can you setup jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ so that I can help you out?

Comment: suppose i type 12 in the gridview textbox the textbox outside the value shows 012 then when i add new row and type a number say 14 it shows 01214..so on

Comment: use 'parseInt(prvVal)+parseInt(val)'  instead 'parseInt(prvVal)+val'

Comment: user2605927 go through  script and debug it according to your requirement...What I have understood ,written that way,. may be your requirement would be some thing else.....if you want me to write the exact code please put your code in jsfiddle